# how to check if fragment exists and is Visible in a container? how to remove it if it exists?

Tags: java, android

I am calling a method that displays some data on button click everytime.
each time the button is clicked i call the method that

- creates a frag object
- bundles data for the frag
- puts data in the frag
- adds the frag to the view in my main Activity
- commits the transaction

i'm then facing a 'Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called'

on the button click i need to check if the frag already exists and then either replace it or something. i'm just confused.

here's the code.

```
public void retrieve_and_display_data(String co) {
     String res = null;

     try {
         res = new getvaluefromservicecall().execute(co, "", "").get();
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (ExecutionException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     List < String > company_stock_details = Arrays.asList(res.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1));

     stock_price_frag frag_obj = new stock_price_frag();



     Bundle b = new Bundle();
     b.putString("Co_name", "data1");
     b.putString("Co_first", "data2");
     b.putString("Co_last", "data3");

     frag_obj.setArguments(b);


     ft.add(R.id.frag_container, frag_obj, "fragment");

     ft.commit();

     //error on commit
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, MainActivity.TAG);
```

use TAG when add fragment to frame layout

and simply add check when button is click

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MainActivity.TAG) instanceof MyFragment)
      //my fragment is visible
 else
      //other fragment is visibile
```